# Fear FOR something vs fear ABOUT something

Tags: prepositions

All these problems make me fear _____________ my children’s future.

Out of 'for' and 'about', is either word more appropriate than the other to be filled in the blank.

The source of this (stand alone) question is a test I've already taken and gives the answer as 'about'.

Comment: "Fear", is used here as a verb. Standard usage would be "make me fear for my children's future". Using the adjectival form we might be "fearful about our children's future". To "fear about" something is not colloquial.

Comment: It is rather odd, I would expect to see "fear for" and "worry about" rather than "fear about". One can "fear" something (for instance "fear disease", "fear war" and so on), "have a fear of" something (such as disease or war) and even "_have_ fears about" something (such as your children's future) but we do not, normally, "fear about" anything without a preposition or other verb.

Comment: Note that when the object of the verb is the thing that causes the fear, it is a direct object (without preposition): *I feared the bear because of its agressive behavior.*

Comment: @phoog Tiny typo: aggressive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage of verb [fear](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=fear):

> Proposition:  ***for*** -  *We feared for their safety.*
>
> Adverb: *genuinely, greatly, really, seriously* -  *This disease is greatly feared. I really feared that this might be the end. | rightly Everyone rightly feared the coming war.*
>
> Verb + FEAR: *seem to | begin to | have little/nothing to* - *You have nothing to fear from him. | have reason to I have reason to fear that you might abuse your power.*

(Oxford Collocation Dictionary)